# How to check if a List<List<int>> contains a List<int>

Tags: c#, list

I have a `List<List<int>>` in which I would like to insert a new `List<int>`. I would like to check before adding the new `List<int>` if it already exists in the `List<List<int>>`.

For e.g.

```
List<List<int>> MasterList = new List<List<int>>();
List<int> childList = new List<int>();
```

I have already tried

```
MaterList.Contains, MasterList.Any
```

but nothing is helping

e.g.

```
MasterList(1)=1,2,3
MasterList(2)=4,5
```

but when I see 1,2,3 or 4,5 is coming again then do not want to enter it as they are already there somewhere in MasterList

Comment: Did you try ALL instead of any.  Use any if you are testing for not matching.  Are you assuming the two lists are in the same order?

Comment: what if `MasterList` contains a list with `4,5` and you attempt to add a list with `5,4`? should that be considered as a list that already exists?

Comment: @ZoharPeled Sir Yes. the 4,5 and 5,4 is same in my scenario

Comment: I gave you the solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use SequenceEqual of Linq

```
if (MasterList.Any(c => c.SequenceEqual(childList)))
{
    //contains

}
```

Comment: This is not what OP asked for, if the sequence is different it doesn't work correctly.

Comment: You could use `OrderBy` to possibly take care of that.

Answer (score 0):

```
 List<List<int>> MasterList = new List<List<int>>();

        List<int> childList1 = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
        List<int> childList2 = new List<int>() { 4, 5 };

        MasterList.Add(childList1);
       //  MasterList.Add(childList2);

        Console.WriteLine(MasterList.Contains(childList1));
        Console.WriteLine(MasterList.Contains(childList2));
        Console.WriteLine(MasterList[0].Contains(1));
        Console.WriteLine(MasterList[0].Contains(7));
//True
//False
//True
//False
```

Perhaps I don't understand what is your problem, sorry.

Comment: The problem OP is facing is that if you had `List<int> childList3 =  new List<int>(){ 1, 2, 3 };`, then `MasterList.Contains(childList3)` would be `false`, even if the elements of `childList1` are the same.

Comment: Ah, but it's obviously, because if you have two list with the same content it's different object and have different addresses. So it means that the question is how to check content of two list object)

Comment: Yes, I believe it is

Answer (score 0):

You can compare two list for equality like this:

```
bool AreListsIdentical(List<int> lhs, List<int> rhs)
{
    if(lhs.Count != rhs.Count) return false;

    return lhs.Zip(rhs, (l,r) => l == r).All(value => value);
}
```

Now, using this function you can use the Linq functions to search for a matching list:

```
List<List<int>> masterList = new List<List<int>>();
List<int> childList = new List<int>(){1, 2, 3};
masterList.Add(childList);

var listToSearchFor = new List<int>{1,2,3};
masterList.Any(list => AreListsIdentical(list, listToSearchFor));
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested following and it works :

```
           List<List<int>> masterList = new List<List<int>>() {
                new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3},
                new List<int>() { 1, 2},
                new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4},
                new List<int>() { 1, 2, 5},
                new List<int>() { 1, 3, 7},
                new List<int>() { 2, 3, 4},
                new List<int>() { 1, 5, 8},
                new List<int>() { 1, 4, 9}
            };

            List<int> newList = new List<int>() { 1,2,5};
            Boolean contains = masterList.Any(x => (x.Count() == newList.Count()) && (x.Select((y, i) => y == newList[i]).All(y => y)));
```

Comment: Couldn't you use `Any` instead of `Select` with the same result? That would avoid having to iterate through all the `List<List<int>>` if the searched list is the first one

Comment: Thanks.  I made the change.  I tried a few things and didn't notice the reduction before posting.

Answer (score 0):

This way:

```
List<List<int>> listOfIntLists = new List<List<int>>() {
    new List<int>(){ 1,2 },
    new List<int>(){ 3,4 },
    new List<int>(){ 5,6 }
};

List<int> integers = new List<int>() { 1, 2 };

if(listOfIntLists.Any(x => x.All(y => integers.Any(z => z == y))) == false)
{
    listOfIntLists.Add(integers);
}
```